# Show the button in the right corner in jsf

Tags: css, jsf

I try to set the button in the right corner above, but the button is hided by accordionPanel.

I did many attempts but non works..

please help!

```
            <p:panel id="previewPanel" styleClass="col-12">
            <h:commandButton name="saveFile" value="save"   --> here the problem.. 
                styleClass="GreenButton"
                actionListener="#{Upload.save()}"
                onclick="saveFunction()"
                style="float:right;width:90px;height:40px">
            </h:commandButton>
                <h:form id="preview" rendered="#{Upload.fileUpload}">
                    <p:accordionPanel widgetVar="basic">
                        <p:tab title="Data Table">
                            <p class="p-m-0">
                                <p:dataTable id="datas" var="data"
<p:dataTable id="datas" var="data"
                                    value="#{Upload.DataRead}"
                                    styleClass="ui-datatable-striped ui-datatable-sm"
                                    tableStyle="width: auto; max-width:100%; white-space:nowrap"
                                    rowKey="#{zre.number}" paginator="true"
                                    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                    paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                    rowClasses="tableRowOdd,tableRowEven" rows="12" cellpadding="3">
                                    <p:column headerText="Nummer">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{zre.Number}" />
                                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                            </p>
                        </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
                </h:form>
            </p:panel>
```

If i add it outside the panel it will be hidden as well. I need to add the button in the first line then the first tab.
Thanks

---

Here: an example:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml?jfwid=588de

Comment: How can i shift the content of the accordionPanel and put my button above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```css
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
width: 90px;
height: 40px;
```

instead of

```css
float: right;
width: 90px;
height: 40px;
```

That will right align the button and it will not be covered by the accordion.